# Cannot open Xcode project after downloading from Google Drive

Tags: xcode

I uploaded an Xcode project folder to Google Drive. However, when I download the folder and try to open the project (filename.xcodeproj), I get the following error:

> "Project path/filename.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file"

Answer (score 0):

It should be inside of your filename.xcodeproj. In Finder, try right clicking it and then choose **Show Package Contents**.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below link could help you to solve your problem like it helped me too!

[After upgrade 0.62.2 to 0.63.2, build fails with LaunchScreen.xib file not found #99](https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/99)

I had the same of your scenario exactly... also I downloaded my project from   google drive and after I spent a full day of searching for the searching I landed on the below topic

[error: Build input file cannot be found: LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753869/error-build-input-file-cannot-be-found-launchscreen-storyboard-and-main-storyb)

Thanks for the @loly sa