# error: Build input file cannot be found: LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I opened this project for the first time in my Mac and when I try to build it, it gives me these tow errors you can see in the screenshots.
I have these file already in the project, I think I only need to set the path for them.
what do you do when you open a project for the first time in you machine?
[a screen shot for the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMErY.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build was successful after I did the fowling:
1- remove the tow files(LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard)and add them again, this is post where I got the solution from https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/99

2- rename the new files and delete .xml at the end

3- select the LaunchScreen as the Main interface
https://i.stack.imgur.com/65P0S.png

Comment: this is where I got the 3rd step from

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have deleted the file LaunchScreen.storyboard. Once check your files.

Comment: here have a look at my files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFPTe-g_xuaduM7k0g-6AkGPUtbU5rdB/view?usp=sharing